# How to moderate ambiguous question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Sometimes on StackExchange I found some question ambiguous.

For example the question and the content of the question for the following question are confused:
[Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch/)

The top answer doesn't answer the question, but answer the content of the question.

In google the query "Git How to fetch a remote branch ?" return this stackoverflow page (because of the question's title).

Depending on which part of the question we focus, the answer is not good.

How to moderate this kind of question before it was popular ?

How to improve the popular question ?

Comment: If you can't understand what the OP is actually asking, leave a comment asking for clarification and/or vote to close as Unclear What You're Asking.

Comment: @Wooble for a popular question this is quite difficult

Comment: @guillaumevincent What is difficult in particular? Commenting or clicking the "close" button? O_o

Comment: @BartoszKP I don't understand, should I remove my question from meta.stackoverflow ?

Comment: @guillaumevincent Why do you think you should remove your question from meta? Ad rem: Question's score is irrelevant. Either it can be improved, or should be closed. Many questions with high score were actually closed, some even deleted. I really don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: Leave the question here. Votes don't really matter, and even though they should only indicate (dis-)agreement only on feature-requests while behaving the same as on main otherwise, sometimes people get it confused.

Comment: @BartoszKP How do you moderate a question becoming ambiguous but too popular ?

Comment: @guillaumevincent I repeat: popularity is irrelevant here. What does "too popular" even mean?

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought I posted my question in the wrong place.

Comment: @guillaumevincent Highly upvoted questions get closed too.  Saying they won't is simply not true.  If the question is unclear then it's not clear.  It's score doesn't change that.  It may be a sign that you simply don't understand it, rather than it being a bad question, so you should look more closely, but that's about it.

Comment: Nope, MSO is the proper meta for SO.

Comment: @BartoszKP 177 stars, 344 up, viewed 261070 times is for me a popular question. I can ask for close as "Unclear What You're Asking" is SO, but I think it will be refuse because the question is "popular"

Comment: @Servy it can be true, maybe I don't understand the question. But my question is more "in general". IMO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch/ is not as good as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch . I found the top not very good.

Comment: @guillaumevincent If the question really is unclear then how popular it is is irrelevant.  The popularity is a red flag that the question might not be unclear, but if it really is, then that has zero impact on how to moderate the question.  Yes, if you refuse to try to moderate the question no moderation action will ever happen.  If you actually take a moderation action, the potential for change is there.

Comment: @Servy I've already try to flag the question

Comment: Really? We're arguing about closing a useful, highly upvoted old question about a common programming tool? There are much better things we can spend our time on, like the piles of trash questions being asked this instant. Deal with all of those first.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm asking what is the best way to improve the question and remove the ambiguity. I don't want to remove the question. Don't waste your time to bite. If you do not like my question, you can downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the amount of *seemingly* quality answers (mostly going by the large amount of upvotes on several answers) along with the upvotes and amount of views on the question itself, closing probably is not the best action here. Though, as others have stated, "popular" questions can be closed and occasionally deleted.

It appears that many people didn't think the question was unclear due to the large amount of answers.

If you think the title and body of the post do not match then suggesting an edit to the title would probably be more appropriate here. If you choose this route, just be sure to go through the post thoroughly and see if there are any other changes to be made. You will also want to explain your reason for the edit clearly in the "Edit Summary" box.

Comment: "It appears that many people didn't think the question was unclear due to the large amount of answers." that is the reason why I didn't try to edit the title. For a lot of questions, I did Google > SO > Copy/Paste > and kaboom, it works. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Well, it's an oft-repeated fallacy: See, there's an answer / I could have answered if those bad guys had not closed it, thus it cannot possibly be unclear.